# How to insert record by minute wise for a single date and start and End date?

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, cursor

I need to generate a record as below:

I have a table `tbl_Graph` with columns `DBName, Size, JobName, StartDate, Enddate`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DBName  |  Size    |   JobName  |       StartTime        |  EndTime       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
DB1     |  13.8    |    JOB1    |       4/7/2013 20:44   |  4/7/2013 21:05|
DB2     |  10.5    |    JOB2    |       4/7/2013 18:20   |  4/7/2013 19:09|
DB3     |  09.10   |    JOB4    |       4/7/2013 3:04    |  4/7/2013 3:23 |
DB4     |  13.8    |    JOB5    |       4/7/2013 11:49   |  4/7/2013 11:54|
DB5     |  10.5    |    JOB3    |       4/7/2013 16:04   |  4/7/2013 16:30|
DB6     |  09.10   |    JOB6    |       4/7/2013 14:02   |  4/7/2013 14:04|
DB7     |  13.8    |    JOB7    |       4/7/2013 20:05   |  4/7/2013 21:21|
DB8     |  10.5    |    JOB8    |       4/7/2013 19:03   |  4/7/2013 19:17|
DB9     |  09.10   |    JOB9    |       4/7/2013 0:17    |  4/7/2013 11:07|
DB10    |  13.8    |    JOB11   |       4/7/2013 1:05    |  4/7/2013 1:40 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I'm specifying from and to date as '4/7/2013' then it will fetch all matched records based on this date and It should generate record each minute based on start and end time of each row.

I need the result set like this

```
---------------------------------
Date             |     JobName  |       
---------------------------------
4/7/2013 20:44   |      JOB1    |       
4/7/2013 20:45   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:46   |      JOB1    |  
4/7/2013 20:47   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:48   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:49   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:50   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:51   |      JOB1    |  
4/7/2013 20:52   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:53   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:54   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:55   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:56   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:57   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:58   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 20:59   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 21:01   |      JOB1    |   
4/7/2013 21:02   |      JOB1    |  
4/7/2013 21:03   |      JOB1    |  
4/7/2013 21:04   |      JOB1    |  
4/7/2013 21:05   |      JOB1    |  
---------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this without any performance issue?

Solution I tried:

I achieved this by using cursor and while loop but it is causing performance issue like taking more than 60 seconds to fetch a record.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
        JobName VARCHAR(10)
      , StartTime DATETIME
      , EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (JobName, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
('JOB1',  '20130704 20:44',  '20130704 21:05'),
('JOB2',  '20130704 18:20',  '20130704 19:09'),
('JOB4',  '20130704 3:04 ',  '20130704 3:23 '),
('JOB5',  '20130704 11:49',  '20130704 11:54'),
('JOB3',  '20130704 16:04',  '20130704 16:30'),
('JOB6',  '20130704 14:02',  '20130704 14:04'),
('JOB7',  '20130704 20:05',  '20130704 21:21'),
('JOB8',  '20130704 19:03',  '20130704 19:17'),
('JOB9',  '20130704 0:17 ',  '20130704 11:07'),
('JOB11', '20130704 1:05 ',  '20130704 1:40 ')

SELECT 
      JobName
    , DateCol = DATEADD(MINUTE, sv.number, StartTime)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          StartTime
        , diff = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)
        , JobName
    FROM @temp
) t
JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv ON sv.number <= diff
WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
```

**Output:**

```
JobName    DateCol
---------- -----------------------
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:44:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:45:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:46:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:47:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:48:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:49:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:50:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:51:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:52:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:53:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:54:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:55:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:56:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:57:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:58:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 20:59:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:00:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:01:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:02:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:03:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:04:00.000
JOB1       2013-07-04 21:05:00.000
...
```

Comment: Thanks Devart....Its help me a lot :)

Comment: If this solution fully suit you, please approve it.